# Select com referência em várias tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tenho três tabelas: `PRODUTOS`, `PEDIDO` e `ESTOQUE`, e quero listar todo o estoque passando por pedido e por produtos, conforme mostro abaixo:

**produtos**

> ```
> codigo    tipo      medida  
> 3020   |  unico  |    3  
> 3021   |  unico  |    5  
> 3022   |  unico  |    7  
> 3023   |  unico  |    3
> ```

**pedido**

> ```
> codigo   qdtpedido  
> 3020   |    10  
> 3021   |    20  
> 3022   |    10  
> 3020   |    5  
> 3021   |    3  
> 3022   |    5
> ```

**estoque**

> ```
> codigo   qdtestoque  
> 3020   |    200  
> 3021   |    150  
> 3022   |    50  
> 3023   |    120
> ```

**Resultado do Select**

> ```
> codigo  qtdestoque   tipo      medida      qtdpedido
> 3020   |   185   |   unico  |    3     |      15      |      
> 3021   |   127   |   unico  |    5     |      23      |      
> 3022   |   35    |   unico  |    7     |      15      |      
> 3023   |   120   |   unico  |    3     |      0       |
> ```

O que estou tentando:

```
SELECT e.*, 
(SELECT sum(qtdpedido) from pedido p where p.modelo = e.codigo) as qtdpedido,   
(SELECT tipo from produtos m where m.codigo = e.codigo) as tipo  
from estoque e ORDER BY codigo ASC;
```

Como resultado preciso listar Estoque (no qual contém todos os produtos), trazendo o campo "tipo" e "medida" que vem da tabela Produtos e somando os "qtdpedidos" referente àquele código.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: O que você precisa é usar cláusulas INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN e RIGHT JOIN https://www.devmedia.com.br/clausulas-inner-join-left-join-e-right-join-no-sql-server/18930

Comment: Suas tabelas estão um pouco confusas... Relacionar a tabela `produtos` com a `estoque` da para fazer, mas você não possui uma tabela `itens_pedidos`? Tem mais campos que você não informou?

Answer (score 2):

Sua estrutura está um pouco confusa, mas pelo que entendi, as três tabelas possuem a coluna `codigo`, que seria o campo de *união* entre elas. Assim sendo, você deve trazer as colunas `p.codigo`, `p.tipo`, `p.medida` que se repetirão para os itens e fazer um somatório de pedidos e estoques, baseando-se nesses dados repetíveis:

```
SELECT p.codigo, p.tipo, p.medida,
   (SELECT SUM(p2.qtdpedido) FROM pedido p2 WHERE p2.codigo = p.codigo) as qtdpedido,
   (SELECT SUM(e2.qdtestoque) FROM estoque e2 WHERE e2.codigo = p.codigo) as qtdestoque
FROM produto p
LEFT JOIN estoque e
GROUP BY e.codigo, p.tipo, p.medida
ORDER BY codigo ASC;
```

Comment: rLinhares, obrigado pela resposta. Editei o que preciso como resultado. É bem parecido com o que comentou ali em cima. Eu não estou usando id aqui, somente codigo. Como resultado preciso listar Estoque (no qual contém todos os produtos), trazendo o campo tipo e medida que vem da tabela Produtos e somando os pedidos referente àquele código.

Comment: @rafB bom ter ajudado =] mas o ideal é que sua pergunta não fique sem resposta, então te indico três alternativas: **1.** alterar esta resposta para aceitá-la **2.** me ajudar a editar esta para que seja aceita =p **3.** criar uma resposta

Comment: 3. Vou criar uma resposta, porém é necessário algumas correções já que apresentou o seguinte erro: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY e.codigo ASC'

Answer (score 0):

Abaixo segue a solução proposta:

```
SELECT e.*,
(SELECT SUM(p.qtdpedido) FROM pedido p WHERE p.codigo = e.codigo) as qtdpedido,
(SELECT tipo FROM produtos m WHERE m.codigo = e.codigo) as tipo
FROM estoque e
LEFT JOIN produtos m 
ORDER BY e.codigo ASC;
```